# Getting a Quantity's value as a BigDecimal

Tags: java, units-of-measurement

When it comes time to get a number back out of a `Quantity`, [getValue()](https://www.javadoc.io/static/javax.measure/unit-api/2.0/javax/measure/Quantity.html#getValue--) returns a `Number`, which can be converted to an `int`, `double`, `float`, `long` or `short`. Seems very strange that there's no way to get it as a `BigDecimal`. Am I missing something or is there a good reason *not* to get it as a `BigDecimal`?

Comment: Where's the implementation of java.measure? I guess it's because they want to use primitive values to keep everything fast and easy. BigDecimal methods can become really slow, because it can basically be an infinitely huge number.

Comment: `BigDecimal` is a subclass of `Number`, so `getValue()` *could* return a `BigDecimal`.  It's just up to the implementation.  As for why that is, think about it the other way around.  If you specify that `getValue()` always returns a `BigDecimal`, then no implementation can ever return anything that isn't a `BigDecimal`.  What if it makes more sense to describe a certain quantity in floating point?  It would be annoying to not have that option available.

Comment: @BenjaminM the implementations of `Quantity` are in the [Indriya](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/indriya/blob/master/src/main/java/tech/units/indriya/quantity/Quantities.java) module. One of them is based on `BigDecimal` which is why it seems weird that I'd have to do `new BigDecimal(quantity.getValue().toString())` to get a `BigDecimal` back out.

Answer (score 2):

I looked through the code of https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/indriya

Here's what's going on:

1. Calling [`Quantities.getQuantity(...)`](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/indriya/blob/bce0c6ea5fcf309d46652464dd61ad187f494560/src/main/java/tech/units/indriya/quantity/Quantities.java#L104) returns a [`new NumberQuantity`](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/indriya/blob/bce0c6ea5fcf309d46652464dd61ad187f494560/src/main/java/tech/units/indriya/quantity/NumberQuantity.java#L69)
2. The `NumberQuantity` constructor calls [`Calculator.peek()`](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/indriya/blob/bce0c6ea5fcf309d46652464dd61ad187f494560/src/main/java/tech/units/indriya/internal/function/Calculator.java#L216)
3. `peek` calls [`NumberSystem.narrow(...)`](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/indriya/blob/b6cbd867ea32acca99821ca385db51fe31adea15/src/main/java/tech/units/indriya/spi/NumberSystem.java#L213)

And this is the interesting part. The method documentation says:

```
* 'Narrows' given {@code number} as a {@link Number} that best
* represents the numeric value within the set of number types this NumberSystem
* supports.
* <p>
* eg. A BigInteger that is within range of Java's {@code Long} type can be narrowed to
* Long w/o loss of precision.
```

The code of [`DefaultNumberSystem.narrow`](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/indriya/blob/bce0c6ea5fcf309d46652464dd61ad187f494560/src/main/java/tech/units/indriya/function/DefaultNumberSystem.java#L419) (the default implementation of the `NumberSystem` interface) shows you how it's done.

In other words: Every time you create a `Quantity` it will get narrowed down. When you have a look at the other `NumberQuantity` methods, you can see that this happens all the time: When you run `add`, `subtract`, etc. there's always a `peek` call involved, which then calls `narrow`.

I guess this is done to speed up calculations. Because using primitives it's a lot faster than using `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger`. And they make sure that you don't lose precision.